# Getting NA value when Date and Time are splited from a single column using R language

Tags: r

In my data set, I have date and time in a single column. In order to convert it as date and time format. I used `as.POSIXct()`.

my code:

```
hourlyIntensities$ActivityHour = as.POSIXct(hourlyIntensities$ActivityHour, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz = Sys.timezone())
```

In order to split the date and time in separate column.
My code to separate date.

```
hourlyIntensities$ActivityDate = format(hourlyIntensities$ActivityHour, format ="%m%d%y")
```

post executing the code, when i check the date column, instead of Date, i could able to see only NA value in the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

First I created a small dataset to simulate your dataset, then modify this dataset as follows:

```
library(stringr)  #for splitting dates
library(dplyr)    
library(data.table) # for transforming date and time
library(tibble) #for creating data.frame(optional)

# Creating a vector simulating your dataset
dates <- c("2015-05-01 00:12","2010-05-01 12:12","2012-05-01 18:00","1998-09-05 00:10", "2021-11-01 14:10","1990-01-01 00:12")
dates <- as.POSIXct(dates, "GMT")

#Creating a tibble(dataframe) simulating your dataframe
hourlyIntensities <- tibble(
  ActivityHour = dates
)

#Original dataset: 
#-----------------------#
hourlyIntensities
## # A tibble: 6 x 1
##   ActivityHour       
##   <dttm>             
## 1 2015-05-01 00:12:00
## 2 2010-05-01 12:12:00
## 3 2012-05-01 18:00:00
## 4 1998-09-05 00:10:00
## 5 2021-11-01 14:10:00
## 6 1990-01-01 00:12:00



#Creating two variables with seperate Date and Time
hourlyIntensities_new <- hourlyIntensities %>%
  mutate(ActivityDate = as.IDate(sapply(hourlyIntensities$ActivityHour, 
                                        function(x) str_split(x, pattern = " ")[[1]][1]))) %>%
  mutate(ActivityHour_new = as.ITime(sapply(hourlyIntensities$ActivityHour, 
                                            function(x) str_split(x, pattern = " ")[[1]][2])))



#Modified dataset
#---------------------------------------#
hourlyIntensities_new
## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   ActivityHour        ActivityDate ActivityHour_new
##   <dttm>              <date>       <ITime>         
## 1 2015-05-01 00:12:00 2015-05-01   00:12:00        
## 2 2010-05-01 12:12:00 2010-05-01   12:12:00        
## 3 2012-05-01 18:00:00 2012-05-01   18:00:00        
## 4 1998-09-05 00:10:00 1998-09-05   00:10:00        
## 5 2021-11-01 14:10:00 2021-11-01   14:10:00        
## 6 1990-01-01 00:12:00 1990-01-01   00:12:00
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: No Bro. In your example, u have defined the date by your own. In my question. I have data set which date and Timestamp in single column

Comment: Share part of your dataset, you did not mention it is in Timestamp format.

Comment: Also in my first dataset time and date are in same column(not two). Then they seperate by str_split into two new columns